# elastic search failed to parse date field with format [strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis]

Tags: laravel, elasticsearch, laravel-scout

To begin with, the date format that that is stored in the index is `2021-09-16T14:06:02.000000Z`

When I log in with the option to `remember` the user and then I log out, I get the following error.

The response from ElasticSearch is

```
array:3 [▼
  "took" => 1
  "errors" => true
  "items" => array:1 [▼
    0 => array:1 [▼
      "index" => array:5 [▼
        "_index" => "users"
        "_type" => "_doc"
        "_id" => "313"
        "status" => 400
        "error" => array:3 [▼
          "type" => "mapper_parsing_exception"
          "reason" => "failed to parse field [created_at] of type [date] in document with id '313'. Preview of field's value: '2021-09-16 11:37:49'"
          "caused_by" => array:3 [▼
            "type" => "illegal_argument_exception"
            "reason" => "failed to parse date field [2021-09-16 11:37:49] with format [strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis]"
            "caused_by" => array:2 [▼
              "type" => "date_time_parse_exception"
              "reason" => "Failed to parse with all enclosed parsers"
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

This happens because when a user logs out, the `remember_token` attribute is modified and since the `User` model is modified, the index is updated.

The problem is that when it tries to update the index, the format of the date it tries to store in the index is not `2021-09-16T14:06:02.000000Z` anymore

Instead, now the date format is `2021-09-16 11:37:49` and therefore there is a conflict in the date format that is already in the index and the date format that it tries to store.

This happens only when the `framework` updates the `User` model, when a user `logs out`.
This does not happen if I update the attribute of any model myself.

`UPDATED`

I just noticed that then `laravel` updates the `remember_token`, it disables the `timestamps` and that is why the date format changes to `2021-09-16 11:37:49`.

However, I still don't know how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 11):

It seem that your application break the rule (date type format) required by Elasticsearch. Type `date` format default to `strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis`, see the [doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/date.html#date-params).

Either you fix your application so that it write `2021-09-16T14:06:02.000000Z` rather than `2021-09-16 11:37:49`, or just `2021-09-16`, because default format
require that, see the doc [Built In Formats](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html#built-in-date-formats):

> `date_optional_time` or `strict_date_optional_time`
>
> A generic ISO datetime parser, where the date must include the year at a minimum, and the time (separated by T), is optional. Examples: `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ` or `yyyy-MM-dd`.

Or you change the mapping of your Elasticsearch index to allow the format of `2021-09-16 11:37:49` use [multiple date formats](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/date.html#multiple-date-formats) when mapping. You will need to explicitly set type of the index (and perform a `_reindex` afterwards to pull the data into your new index if necessary).

```
PUT my-index-000001
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "created_at": {
        "type":   "date",
        "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss||strict_date_optional_time ||epoch_millis"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` format should be able to parse your data entry similar to `2021-09-16 11:37:49`.

Hopefully this will help.

Comment: I have tried many formats but still not working.

Answer (score 1):

I just faced the same issue and this format solved my problem: `2023-01-10 20:15:25.000+0300`.

Other formats I had tried but not working:

- `2022-01-01`
- `2021-09-16 11:37:49`
- `2023-01-19 05:30:00.000Z`
- `2023-01-19 05:30:00.0000`